# Laravel 5 validate csv file error on valid file type

Tags: php, validation, csv, laravel

I am trying to validate an uploaded csv file with

```
$validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'file'      => $file,
            'extension' => strtolower($file->getMimeType()),
        ],
        [
            'file'      => 'required|in:csv',
        ]
    );
```

The validator fails on giving a valid csv file with message `The file must be a file of type: csv.`

The validator passes if i remove `in:csv`.

Am i doing something wrong?

PS - `$file` is available and of standard upload file type `object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    [
        'file'      => $file,
        'extension' => strtolower($file->getMimeType()),
    ],
    [
        'file'      => 'required|in:csv',
    ]
);
```

To

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    [
        'file'      => $file,
        'extension' => strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
    ],
    [
        'file'          => 'required',
        'extension'      => 'required|in:csv',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Tried that. Gives the same error. PS - I am using Laravel 5

Comment: Okay what is the error when using mimes? Also why are you not using a request for your validation, if using Laravel 5

Comment: Okay I see what you are doing now,

Comment: how to get this in Request object?

Comment: what is $file ?? what you storing in $file ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're uploading a CSV file, you should allow the following mime types:

```
'application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv'
```

Also in Laravel 5:

```
$rules =  [
    'file'          => 'required',
    'extension'      => 'required|mimes:csv'
];
```

From the docs: (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation)

> The Validator class provides several rules for validating files, such
>   as **size**, **mimes**, and others. When validating files, you may simply pass
>   them into the validator with your other data.

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

```
//custom vaildation for csv file
$this->validate(request(), [
    'file' => ['required',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if (!in_array($value->getClientOriginalExtension(), ['csv','xsl','xsls'])) {
            $fail('Incorrect :attribute type choose.');
        }
    }]
]);
```

Comment: No need to do  any extra thing, you just copy above code & use. its work for any type of mimes validation.