# Validate CSV file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv, request

I am trying to upload a CSV file and I want to validate it before doing anything else. So I use the following code in my FormRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'csvFile' => 'required|file|mimes:csv'
    ];
}
```

The form i use for uploading the file is:

```
<form action="{{ route('uploadFile') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fileToUpload">CSV File to upload</label>
        <input name="csvFile" type="file" class="form-control" id="fileToUpload" placeholder="Select file">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that it does not work. Trying to check the mime type of my test.csv file using getMimeType() I get:

```
"text/plain"
```

but if I use getClientMimeType() I get:

```
"text/csv"
```

From what I read is that:

> The client mime type (*getClientMimeType()*) is
>   extracted from the request from which the file was uploaded, so **it
>   should not be considered as a safe value**.
>
> For a **trusted mime type**, use *getMimeType()* instead (which guesses the
>   mime type based on the file content).

Obviously, I should use getMimeType(), but it will not work (at least most of the times).

I tried to imitate this by doing:

```
end(explode('.', $file->getClientOriginalName()));
```

This will return 'csv' as a result, but it feels like a hack! Also, it can be fooled easily.

Is there a way to safely know if a file is of type .csv?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your file name of csv file in test case ?

Comment: please add the form you are uploading file with, likely that you must include 'files' => 'true'

Comment: Your validation also fails if your file name contains space

Comment: form added in question

Comment: look at this question, this might help you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/csv-file-upload-request-validation

Comment: what the point is of this kind of validation? you need actually read the file to make sure it is a real csv file, IMO mime guessing is no better than client header.

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson: How would you do it?

Comment: @christostsang try to load the uploaded content with `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson I use this PHP method after validation to get the data of .csv file.

Comment: @christostsang than why you want to validate input? while you could catch all the errors when read it.

Comment: maybe this is the answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159933/laravel-5-validate-csv-file-error-on-valid-file-type

Answer (score 13):

you can use `required|mimes:csv,txt` for validation **csv** file.

Comment: Although is too late, validating the txt mime will allow  ANY txt files, even any .sql file.

Answer (score 3):

As CSV is basically a text-file, so its mime-type is checked against the file extension. Does your file have a .csv extension?

If you want to allow .txt extension as well, change your validation rule to this:

```
return [ 'csv_import' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt' ];
```

Comment: Although is too late, validating the txt mime will allow  ANY txt files, even any .sql file.